How does flutter web and android security works if various values can be known to any one , and waht is the purpose of so many values?
I was trying to understand how does flutter security works.
An android apk can be de-compileed and google-services.json can be retrieved. Similarly if using flutter web, all the various keys associated with app can be looked.
While searching on internet at some documents it is suggested to keep these value secret at other documents it is suggested to keep these value safe( not secret).
For web based flutter application, I could simply go to developer tools and search code from source.
Second question is, What is the meaning of these values in FirebaseOptions?
if (kIsWeb) {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
   options: FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: "39characters",
      authDomain: "myapp-id-123.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://myapp-id-123-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "myapp-id-123",
      storageBucket: "myapp-id-123.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "123456789012",
      appId: "1:123456789012:web:12345d321aa0245b3a21b2",
      measurementId: "G-G1D0123AA1"
     ), );
  } else {
   await Firebase.initializeApp();
  }

Is there a authoritative documents from google that confirms that it is ok to share these values.

@frank-van-puffelen I suppose  messagingSenderId, appId and measurementId are also just identifying information and can be shared publicly similar to public key of certificate, private key is with google. In question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/ we should add messagingSenderId, appId and measurementId  ?
